# ASP.NET MVC 3 - tell partialview to regrab the viewdata values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Let's say I have a partial view X.ascx like this:

```
<div id = "updateTargetIdForAjaxForm">
... javascript code which only has function definitions.
... ajax form with buttons inside
    <div id = "stuff"></div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
       do things to "stuff" div as soon as X.ascx is loaded. 
    </script>
</div>
```

Now I want to update things on X.ascx, based on Ajax response. Earlier, I was returning PartialView but inline javascript that does things to stuff div wouldn't like that, meaning the inline javascript just won't get executed when X.ascx is reloaded.

So is there a way I can not return PartialView in my controller, but just update ViewData values and tell the PartialView to re-grab the updated ViewData values? And also call one or two javascript functions based on the response from server maybe?

Comment: you could try disabling the ajax caching and see how it works. here is how you can do this $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways to go:

Fixing your javascript code to run with dynamically loaded partial view:

- http://api.jquery.com/live/
- http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

These two should help you out.

The other way is to create an action on your controller that would return JSON result and from jQuery you should be able to handle JSON object and update your form. Your Action could look like :

```
public JsonResult GetFormValues()
{
    var jsonFormValues = new
    {

        key1 = "abc",
        key2 = "123",
        key3 = "abcdef"

    };
    return Json(jsonFormValues, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and check out http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ on how to handle the result